# reverse chain of nodes python

Tags: python-3.x

Need some help with something I'm working on regarding making a chain of nodes. I need to move the last index to the second index using a the Node class which I have imported.

```
from Node import Node:
def reverse_chain(list):
  if list is None: return 
    head = list 
    tail = list.next 
    reverse_chain(tail) 
    print(head,end = " ")
```

This is the code I wrote but at the moment it doesn't make sense so I'm still working on it

**my node.py file has this code in it:**

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, init_data):
    self.data = init_data
    self.next = None

def get_data(self):
    return self.data

def get_next(self):
    return self.next

def set_data(self, new_data):
    self.data = new_data

def set_next(self, new_next):
    self.next = new_next

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)
```

**I am trying to produce this output:**

```
node_1 = Node('John')
node_2 = Node('Bill')
node_3 = Node('monkey')
node1.set_next(node2)
node2.set_next(node3)
reverse_chain(node1)
print(node1.get_data(), end = ' ')
print(node1.get_next().get_data(), end = ' ')
print(node1.get_next().get_next().get_data(), end = ' ')
should produce John monkey Bill
```